# ggplot: how to make color inside aes takes in parameter as a hex code for color instead of using it as a factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

The color argument inside aes always treats string as different factors for example

```
colors = colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))(3)
#colors is a list of hex code for colors ranging from red to blue

dt = data.table(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(3,2,1), level = c(1,2,3))

ggplot(dt)+geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = colors[level]))
```

This will not use hex codes as inputs for colors but just different factors. Is there any way the color parameter inside aes can actually use the hex codes? I know there are ways to do it outside aes but i need to make color dependent on level in data. Specifically i want to plot a geom_point() where the the points are from light blue to dark blue depending on its level (and overlay another geom_point() with a different color. So i need to be able to specify color palette. )

Thank you.

Comment: Would mind terribly providing working R code?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `I(...)` around a field, `ggplot2` interprets it as an identity (real color), not as a factor.

Code corrected for syntax errors.

```r
colors = colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(3)
dt = data.table(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(3,2,1), level = c(1,2,3))
ggplot(dt) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = I(colors[level])), size = 5)
```

(`size` expanded just for demo here.)

[image: ggplot2]

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me. and sorry for syntax errors i corrected them in the original post.